# JavaScript json value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON `var response` (See below) but I can't retreive the value of "reputation" using `response.users[0].reputation`. I am in Dashcode and it says in error `Result of expression response.users[unknown] is not an object`. What is the correct syntax?

**edit: The variable is dynamically loaded from a `XMLHttpRequest`. A static var with same json is working.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess from `XMLHttpRequest` you recieve string but not json object, so you need parse it first in order to get json object, for example using [JSON.Parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) or [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and `response.users[0].reputation` should work.

Comment: @umar: I've added references to my answer.

Comment: thx - this is working `var res = JSON.parse(response);` and then `res.users[0].reputation`

Comment: @umar: Cool, but be care before *JSON.Parse* may not worк in all browsers. I usual copy JSON.Parse code and paste in my own js file. It just a few rows..

Answer (score 3):

The JSON is fine. I just checked it and "response.users[0].reputation". (Second pair of eyes and all that.)

I would be more concerned about the "unknown" in "response.users[unknown]". It doesn't look like you are requesting the 0th index of the array "users". Something's going wrong there.

Comment: The variable is dynamically loaded from a XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

Personnally when i test the syntax of your Json, it is correct :
http://www.jsonlint.com

I have just deleted the comment "//need to get its value".

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me as you have done it. Maybe you are not assigning the variable correctly (`var response = {"total": 1, etc...`) or have a typo somewhere

Comment: The variable is dynamically loaded from a XMLHttpRequest